# How to debug a configuration object, when testing?

Tags: 8, testing

I write tests for a custom module using Drupal\simpletest\WebTestBase. I can not find a method, how to debug the configuration object.

I tried e.g. the following commands:

```
$config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings');

debug($config); // AJAX-HTTP-Error
debug(get_object_vars($config)); // Empty array
debug($config->getRawData()); // Empty array
debug($config->getOriginal()); // Empty array
dump($config); // AJAX-HTTP-Error
var_dump($config); // Needs extremely long time
ksm($config); // Nothing is shown
kint($config); // Nothing is shown
dpm($config); // ServiceNotFoundException
dpm($config->toArray()); // AJAX-HTTP-Error
dsm(get_object_vars($config)); // ServiceNotFoundException
print_r($config); // Needs extremely long time
```

The debug() command works fine for arrays and strings (and is nice integrated in the test report).

```
 debug($var, 'Label');
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be able to see in the config object? Bear in mind the storage is probably lazy; it's not like there's an array in there somewhere with every single config key and value in it, values are likely to be loaded when requested

Comment: I would like to see an array with all available settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Config::get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Config.php/function/Config%3A%3Aget/8.2.x), for which:

> If no key is specified, then the entire data array is returned.

e.g.

```
debug(\Drupal::config('mymodule.settings')->get());
```

Comment: Thanks. I have found, that also debug(\Drupal::config('mymodule.settings')->geRawDatat()); works. The problem is, that I receive from both an empty array. But it is some other problem. (When I use \Drupal::config('system.site'), then I receive correct array.)